# scipy -- how to put randomly one array into another?

Tags: python, scipy

i want to do this:

Lets say i have `N=100` and `myone=scipy.ones(N)` which shape is: `myone.shape=100`,
I  want the array `myzeros=scipy.zeros(c*N)` ,`c=0.1` to be inserted randomly in the `myone` array without changing the dimensions of the `myone`.

Comment: You want to insert the whole array myzeros at random locations in myones?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import scipy as sc
myone = sc.ones(100)
ind = sc.random.permutation(100)[:10]
myone[ind] = 0
```